# Change SliderDrawer Icon

Tags: smartface.io

whats I need to do to change the icon on top left? (SmartFaceIcon)

[SliderDrawerIcon](http://www.smartface.io/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Androidss-169x300.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should use dynamic slider drawer for the first page and you can define it in Global.Smartface.js, such as :

```
var mySliderDrawer = new SMF.UI.SliderDrawer({
        position : SMF.UI.SliderDrawerPosition.left,
        icon : "myicon.png"
    });
Pages.Page1.add(mySliderDrawer);
```

For other pages, you can use both dynamic or static and change the icon simply before you show the page. If you use static, you can change its icon as below :

```
Pages.Page2.SliderDrawer1.icon = "myicon.png";
Pages.Page2.show();
```

Be sure you set your icon(myicon) in the resource folder.

Comment: not work, I don't understand why my intellisense don't provide ".icon" property... my smartface app studio version is 4.3.0

Comment: That's my code:
    function Global_Events_OnStart(e) {    
    //Create a sliderDrawer object
    var slider_drawer = new SMF.UI.SliderDrawer({
            width : '30%',
            touchEnabled : 'true',
            backgroundColor : 'red',
            position : 'left',
            icon : 'icon.png'
        });    
    Pages.Home.add(slider_drawer);    
}

Comment: Try to write this code above Global onStart function, not inside any function in Global.Smartface.js

Comment: don't work, is there any trouble with my version of ap studio?  http://docs.smartface.io/html/AllMembers_T_SMF_UI_SliderDrawer.htm don't have any member like icon